# R Missing Package error when uploading to shinyapps.io

Tags: package, shiny-server

My Shiny program works fine locally on my PC (Windows 8, RStudio 0.99.489) but not when I upload it to shinyapps.io . I've tried 2 ways of packaging the data for upload - saveRDS on each object and save.image on the entire environment.  Either way, when I upload it to shiny.io I get:

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 77966...DONE
Deploying bundle: 350891 for application: 77966 ...
Waiting for task: 132618597
  building: Parsing manifest
  building: Building image: 344796
  building: Installing packages
################################ Begin Task Log ################################ 
[2016-01-16T22:19:45.818533554+0000] Installing R package: magrittr (1.5)
Error in library(stylo) : there is no package called �stylo�
Execution halted
################################# End Task Log     ################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 132618599 failed: Error building      image: Build exited with non-zero status: 1
Execution halted
```

It seems that Shiny isn't aware of the Stylo package.  I tried to install it in my code, but that didn't help.
1. Does Shiny have all R packages?
2. If not, is there a list of which packages are available?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the `stylo` package at the top of your `server.R` file via `library("stylo")`? If you *are* doing that and it's giving you the error, [try using `require("stylo")` instead](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html#comment-2343612953).

From [the docs](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html#package-dependencies), the `rsconnect` package is supposed to automatically detect what packages are necessary for your app. Probably worth a read (if you haven't already) just to be sure you're following everything correctly in order for `rsconnect` to do its job.

Comment: Thanks adilapapaya, but it didn't help. The documentation says that rsconnect can download packages from CRAN, BioConductor and GitHub, and Stylo is definitely on CRAN.  But the error persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing a clean build of my environment -- imported data tables and functions from RDS files only, and carefully avoided references to unnecessary packages.  I recreated the one function I needed from Stylo locally, so that I could be certain I wouldn't require it.